# Routes with multiple views

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm trying to do in my project, that a single page of my page
of `[routerLink]` able to display the information of the selected component. What I intend is:

1. Login [X]
2. User / Administrator of the interface [X]
3. Navigate the administrator's components [?]

In point three, it is where I was left blank because when the User logs in
access the Administrator role, and it contains a sidebar where there are different options to choose from and
show in a section the information of each selected component. So, the problem is that it is an Administrator component (father), a child component must be loaded, which I do not know how to do it?

**Example of Dashboard**
[image: Dashboard]

This is part of my code:

**app.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path:'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path:'administrator',
    component: AdministratorComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  { path: 'information', component: InformationComponent },
  { path: 'operator', component: OperatorComponent },
  { path: 'configuration-bill', component: ConfigurationBillComponent },
  { path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: "/error"
  }
];
```

**AdministratorComponent**

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <!-- this section always has to be there TOP side-->
    <app-barra-nav></app-barra-nav>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="container-fluid" >
      <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">          
          <div class="list-group">
            <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action text-center text-primary h6">
              SETTINGS <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse text-left">
              <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action h6" [routerLink]="['/configuration-bill']" routerLinkActive="active">
                <i class="far fa-newspaper"></i>
                Set up your bill
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action h6" [routerLink]="['/print-label']" routerLinkActive="active">
                <i class="fas fa-print"></i>
                ¡Print Labels!
              </button>
              <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action h6" [routerLink]="['/information']" routerLinkActive="active">
                <i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i>
                Information
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="col-md-10">
         <!-- here should be charge the child components -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks, I hope to have been clear on the aforementioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need a child router outlet:

```
    <div class="col-md-10">
     <!-- here should be charge the child components -->
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

Then any routes that go into *that* router outlet need to be children of the admin component.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path:'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path:'administrator',
    component: AdministratorComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'information', component: InformationComponent },
      { path: 'operator', component: OperatorComponent },
      { path: 'configuration-bill', component: ConfigurationBillComponent },
    ]
  },
  { path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: "/error"
  }
];
```

NOTE: I copied and pasted your code here and hand edited it. I did NOT syntax check this. Use the above for a general idea of the code you need.

I have a youtube video that demonstrates child routes (and some other routing techniques) here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaIAHOSKHCQ&t=5s

And you can find sample code here:

https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-routing

and here:

https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing

Comment: Hi, yes, but the Administrator.component is charged in that tag of Angular. So, How can I use the others components without change the component Administrator. I need a component to load another component from the same component. Because, I've started this project like you said, "Administrator" in `app.component` but when I had to make a Login all this change (I'm lost!)

Comment: Did you look at any of the links to the sample code? I have complete and working examples (WITH a login page!).

Comment: Yes, I'm watching your video and examples, I'm testing. by the way, great explications, your speach so clear!

Comment: Thanks, your solution was correct and thanks again for your documentation, I'm learnig more!